# File paths with XSLT includes

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm working on a website with a large number of pages, and each one has this in it: 
`<xsl:include href="team-menu.xsl" />`

This xsl file is stored in the root directory.

Essentially including my "team menu" on each page. My problem is when I include this on nested pages, e.g. "/teammembers/smith.xsl", the links in the menu are broken because they refer to pages that aren't in the same directory as the page i'm viewing.

This is probably really easy, but I just don't know how to fix it.  Is there a way to tell the XSL the root directory and/or set some sort of global directory? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you could just use absolute links, instead of relative ones.

I.e. `/index.xml` instead of `index.xml`.

Comment: I just ended up doing this, which I initially wanted to avoid because of local display issues, but it still works!

Answer (score 1):

You can use XSL parameters to pass the base directory. All processors come with a mechanism for passing these (eg `xsltproc --stringparam basedir style`). Within your stylesheet, you should be able to use something like the following to consume the parameter:

```
<xsl:param name="basedir" />
<xsl:include href="{$basedir}/team-menu.xsl" />
```