# Parameterize path to import a xslt from other xslt

Tags: xslt, include

I am trying to parametrize a path to include a xslt file into other, I have been trying with the way described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016945/file-paths-with-xslt-includes):

```
<xsl:param name="basedir" />
<xsl:include href="{$basedir}/team-menu.xsl" />
```

and call to the xslt doing: 
`xsltproc --stringparam basedir style example.xslt example.xml`

But no way. I am not abel to do it work.  It seems like if the xsl:output element was related because the only way I could make it "work" was this:

```
<xsl:include href="the/path/to/file/team-menu.xsl" />
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="basedir" />
```

I mean... putting the *param* after the *output* and the *include* before. Big problem: I can´t use the variable basedir.

Any way to do this??

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 3.0 you can do this provided the parameters are declared as static, which means the values have to be supplied at compile time. You also need to prefix the attribute with "_":

```
<xsl:param name="basedir" static="yes"/>
<xsl:include _href="{$basedir}/team-menu.xsl" />
```

The reason it doesn't work with ordinary variables should be fairly obvious: variable values aren't known until run-time, and you can't start execution until you have found all the source code making up the stylesheet.

What you can do with earlier releases of XSLT, depending on the processor, is to redirect `xs:include`/`xs:import` URIs from the API level, for example (on Java) by using a user-supplied URIResolver.